# AWS Route 53 wildcard subdomain with Api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, subdomain, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53, wildcard-subdomain

I have a Hosted zone name example.com on AWS Route53 DNS service.
I have multiple subdomain record sets like:

```
api.example.com - type A - ALIAS xxx.cloudfront.net
www.example.com - type A - ALIAS xxx.cloudfront.net
app.example.com - type A - ALIAS xxx.cloudfront.net
```

All the records point to a Cloudfront generated by Api Gateway Custom Domain.

I want to offer a custom subdomain to all of my users:

```
USERNAME.example.com
alice.example.com
bob.example.com
...
```

I do not know in advance the username of all my users and there can be 1000s of them.

How can I setup Route53 to route all non defined subdomains to a specific Cloudfront => Api Gateway => AWS Lambda instance?

Comment: Have you tried creating a wildcard SSL certificate in Virginia Region in AWS Certificate Manager and assign to the Cloudfront distribution?

Comment: I did created a wildcard SSL certificate but the certificate and the wildcard subdomain for Cloudfront => Api Gateway are two different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wildcard custom domains are now supported by AWS API Gateway.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html#wildcard-custom-domain-names

Answer (score 6):

From amazon route53 docs:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/DomainNameFormat.html

> Using an Asterisk (*) in the Names of Hosted Zones and Records You can
>   create hosted zones that include * in the name. Note the following:
>
> You can't include an * in the leftmost label in a domain name. For
>   example, *.example.com is not allowed.
>
> If you include * in other positions, DNS treats it as an * character
>   (ASCII 42), not as a wildcard.
>
> You can also create records that include * in the name. DNS treats the
>   * character either as a wildcard or as the * character (ASCII 42), depending on where it appears in the name. Note the following
>   restrictions on using * as a wildcard in the name of records:
>
> The * must replace the leftmost label in a domain name, for example,
>   *.example.com. It can't replace any of the middle labels, for example, marketing.*.example.com.
>
> The * must replace the entire label. For example, you can't specify
>   *prod.example.com or prod*.example.com.
>
> You can't use the * as a wildcard for records that have a type of NS.
>
> For records, if you include * in any position other than the leftmost
>   label in a domain name, DNS treats it as an * character (ASCII 42),
>   not as a wildcard.

After that you can get the subdomain of the request within your API and perform a certain action for it, e.g., select a user by username using subdomain.

<strike>**EDIT:**
Unfortunately AWS API Gateway does not support wild-card subdomain name as we can see in the first point of this link:
[Api Gateway Known Issues](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-known-issues.html)</strike>

**EDIT 2:**
Now the AWS API Gateway has support for wild-card subdomains:
[API Gateway Wild Card sub domain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html#wildcard-custom-domain-names) Thanks @justin tailor

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned, API Gateway doesn't support wildcard domains.

However, you can achieve the same thing with a load balancer (though it costs ~$17/month).

1. Under EC2 > Load balancers, create an ALB
2. Point it to your lambda function
3. In Route53, set up *.yourdomain.com as an A alias to the ALB